# How can you redraw a bitmap?

Tags: java

I get the byte[] b from another intent, and the array isn't empty. But when I use this code, the bitmap I drawed in the other activity isn't drawed in this activity. Does anyone know how to help me?

```
public void setImageBitmap(byte[] b) {
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    //mBitmap.recycle();
}
```

Comment: `if (mBitmap != null) canvas.drawBitmap(...);` of course.

Comment: Dit doesn't work, and I already put this as you can see in onDraw

Comment: My comment wanted to hint, that when `setImageBitmap` is _not_ called before the first `onDraw` the drawing could throw a NullPointerException on `mBtmap`. As there still is no answer, store the bytes, so you can inspect them: length, byte values.